# Dividing Harmonic Number's Denominator

Tags: number-theory

Why is it that $3$ divides most of the denominators of the harmonic numbers up to 68, but after that none (at least that's what I think) are divisible by $3$? The sequence of numbers I am referring to is https://oeis.org/A002805.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your arithmetic is wrong. E.g. we have 
$$H_{70} = \frac{42535343474848157886823113473}{8801320137209899102584580800}$$
and this means for the denominator
$$8801320137209899102584580800 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
On the contrary (if I did not make mistakes myself) I found that in the list 
https://oeis.org/A002805/b002805.txt
the only numbers $H_n$ with $n\le 200$ with denominators not divisible by $3$ are
$ H_{1}, H_{8}, H_{21}, H_{22}, H_{66}, H_{67}, H_{68}$ with a remainder $1$ and $H_{2}, H_{6}, H_{7}, H_{23}$ with remainder $2$.

Update: I found no $H_n$ with denominator **not** divisible by 3 for $68 < n \le 10000.$